# REACT-NATIVE Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having the following error "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `TitleScreen`."

I've got the import/export shown here:

TitleScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ImageBackground, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { AdMobBanner } from 'expo';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const screenX = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const screenY = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default class TitleScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <ImageBackground
                source={require('../assets/space_background.png')}
                style={{width: screenX, height: screenY}}
            >
                <View style={styles.isJustGameContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.isJustGameText}>Is Just Game</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Space Shooter</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.playerStats}>
                    <Text style={styles.playerStatText}>
                        High Score: {this.props.highScore}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.playerStatText}>
                        Enemies Destroyed: {this.props.allEnemiesDestroyed}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.playerStatText}>
                        Coins Collected: {this.props.allCoinsCollected}
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.titleScreenContainer}>
                    <ImageBackground 
                        source={require('../assets/player_large.png')}
                        style={styles.titleImage}
                    >
                    </ImageBackground>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.buttonContainer}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.props.playMenuNavigation();
                            this.props.startGame()
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                            Start Game
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.buttonContainer}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.props.playMenuNavigation();
                            this.props.openControls();
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                            Controls
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.buttonContainer}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.props.playMenuNavigation();
                            this.props.openInfo()
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>
                            About
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.adMobBanner}>
                    <AdMobBanner
                        bannerSize="fullBanner"
                        adUnitID="ca-app-pub-5830175342552944/8024421682"
                        testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
                    />
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        )
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, ImageBackground, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import Expo from 'expo';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import Player from './components/Player.js';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { GameEngine } from 'react-native-game-engine';
import GameLogic from './GameLogic.js';
import TitleScreen from './views/TitleScreen';
import Info from './views/Info.js';
import Controls from './views/Controls.js';
import EndGameScreen from './views/EndGameScreen.js';
import Config from './config/Config.js';
import EntitySizes from './config/EntitySizes.js';

export default class App extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.screenX = Dimensions.get('window').width;
        this.screenY = Dimensions.get('window').height;
        this.playerWidth = 50;
        this.menuNavigation = new Audio.Sound();
        this.menuNavigation.loadAsync(require('./assets/sound_bits/menu_navigation.mp3'));
        this.state = {
            // Current Game Stats
            points: 0,
            coinsCollected: 0,
            shotsFired: 0,
            enemiesDestroyed: 0,
            playerHealth: Config.gameDefaults.playerHealth,

            // Player Stats
            highScore: 0,
            allEnemiesDestroyed: 0,
            allCoinsCollected: 0,

            shotsLeft: Config.gameDefaults.shotsLeft,
            hasGameStarted: false,
            hasGameEnded: false,
            isInfoOpen: false,
            isControlsOpen: false,
            causeOfEnd: '',
        };
    }
    
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.GameLogic = new GameLogic(this.setState.bind(this));
        this.readerPlayerStats();
    }

    readerPlayerStats = () => {
        AsyncStorage.multiGet(['highScore', 'allEnemiesDestroyed', 'allCoinsCollected']).then(res => {
            let tempHighScore = 0;
            let tempAllEnemiesDestroyed = 0;
            let tempAllCoinsCollected = 0;

            // highScore
            if (res[0][1] !== null) {
                tempHighScore = String(res[0][1]);
            }
            // tempAllEnemiesDestroyed
            if (res[1][1] !== null) {
                tempAllEnemiesDestroyed = String(res[1][1]);
            }
            // tempAllCoinsCollected
            if (res[2][1] !== null) {
                tempAllCoinsCollected = String(res[2][1]);
            }

            this.setState({
                highScore: tempHighScore,
                allEnemiesDestroyed: tempAllEnemiesDestroyed,
                allCoinsCollected: tempAllCoinsCollected,
            })
        });
    }

    backToTitleScreen = () => {
        this.GameLogic.resetGame();
        this.setState({
            hasGameStarted: false,
            hasGameEnded: false,
            isInfoOpen: false,
            isControlsOpen: false,
            points: 0,
            coinsCollected: 0,
            shotsLeft: Config.gameDefaults.shotsLeft,
            playerHealth: Config.gameDefaults.playerHealth,
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.hasGameStarted)
        {
            return (
                <ImageBackground
                    source={require('./assets/space_background.png')}
                    style={{width: this.screenX, height: this.screenY}}
                >
                    <GameEngine
                        style={styles.gameContainer}
                        systems={[
                            this.GameLogic.gameLoop,
                            this.GameLogic.movePlayer,
                            this.GameLogic.fireProjectile,
                            this.GameLogic.chanceToSpawnEnemy,
                            this.GameLogic.chanceToSpawnFallingCollectible,
                            this.GameLogic.chanceToSpawnFallingHeart,
                            this.GameLogic.chanceToSpawnAsteroid,
                            this.GameLogic.playAgain,
                        ]}
                        entities={{
                            1: {
                                name: 'Player',
                                size: EntitySizes.PLAYER_SIZE,
                                circle: EntitySizes.PLAYER_CIRCLE,
                                health: this.state.playerHealth,
                                position: [this.screenX / 2 - this.playerWidth / 2, this.screenY - 100],
                                renderer: <Player/>
                            },
                            // @Dev to set static object, make sure entity doesn't have name an is in the visible field
                            // 2: {
                            //     position: [this.screenX / 3 - this.playerWidth / 2, this.screenY - 100],
                            //     renderer: <Projectile/>
                            // }
                        }}
                    >
                        <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
                        <EndGameScreen
                            playMenuNavigation={() => this.menuNavigation.replayAsync()}
                            points={this.state.points}
                            shotsFired={this.state.shotsFired}
                            enemiesDestroyed={this.state.enemiesDestroyed}
                            hasGameEnded={this.state.hasGameEnded} //@TODO this.state.hasGameEnded
                            playAgain={(value) => this.GameLogic.setPlayAgain(value)}
                            backToTitleScreen={() => this.backToTitleScreen()}
                        />
                    </GameEngine>
                </ImageBackground>
            );
        }
        else if (!this.state.hasGameStarted && !this.state.isInfoOpen && !this.state.isControlsOpen) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
                    <TitleScreen
                        playMenuNavigation={() => this.menuNavigation.replayAsync()}
                        startGame={() => this.setState({hasGameStarted: true})}
                        openControls={() => this.setState({isControlsOpen: true})}
                        openInfo={() => this.setState({isInfoOpen: true})}
                        allCoinsCollected={this.state.allCoinsCollected}
                        allEnemiesDestroyed={this.state.allEnemiesDestroyed}
                        highScore={this.state.highScore}
                    />
                </View>
            );
        }
        else if (!this.state.hasGameStarted && this.state.isInfoOpen) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
                    <Info
                        closeInfo={() => this.setState({isInfoOpen: false})}
                        playMenuNavigation={() => this.menuNavigation.replayAsync()}
                    />                     
                </View>
            )
        }
        else if (!this.state.hasGameStarted && this.state.isControlsOpen) {
            return(
                <View>
                    <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
                    <Controls
                        closeControls={() => this.setState({isControlsOpen: false})}
                        playMenuNavigation={() => this.menuNavigation.replayAsync()}
                    />                    
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the import in App.js with `import TitleScreen from './views/TitleScreen.js';`  but it throws me the same error.

Comment: No, it is different. In my case I'm not using any select tag or type = "select". So I don't know why it throws me the error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error by checking all the imports

**For example
i had to change this**

```
import TouchableWithoutFeedbackBase from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';  // i have no idea how this got imported like this!
```

**To this**

```
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have extended TitleScreen from Component without import it,
you have to do :

**1** `import React from 'react';`

**2**  `export default class TitleScreen extends React.Component`

Comment: In the code it doesn't show but indeed I import React

```
1 import React, { Component } from 'react';

2 export default class TitleScreen extends React.Component { .. }
``` 

But still got the same error.